# Incorrect date insertion in mongo db

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework

I am inserting date in mongo db whenever i insert some future date in mongo db . it insert it in minus one hour for example when my date is

```
`19-10-2016 00:00:00`
```

it will insert

```
`"control_date_dropdown_1" : ISODate("2016-10-18T23:00:00.000Z")`
```

which is incorrect